# Get the user's GPS location and store it

Tags: android, gps

It want  to keep an array (Java generics for example: List) of the last 10 coordinates in order of retrieval so latest coordinates are always at the top of the stack etc. If I ask for this array we can then go back to see what steps the user took by tracing there steps.Please help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to read about how to retrive the user GPS location.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Then make your class implement android.location.LocationListener and in the onLocationChanged() callback just add the location to the list.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   list.add(location);
}
```

Comment: I have gps location i just need ordering last in first.But i solved the problem.thanks